# What is the assumed subject of -u form verbs

Tags: verbs, grammar

Something that came up in an answer to my previous question was, what is the assumed subject of a u-form verb, which I incorrectly assumed to always be *vi*.  When I say *Kuru!*, or *Sidiĝu!* I really mean a command directed towards a specific person.  But it was mentioned that *Pluvu!* is valid and I am really meaning *Let it rain!*, rather commanding somebody specific to start raining.  Similarly, *Estu!* can mean *Let it be so!*  The question then is, how do I get this right.  What if I want to command the rain god to start raining.  *Pluvu!* seems correct then.  Is this simply something to get out of context?  If I am yelling at Hamlet during the play (a sure way to get kicked out of the theater), I want to yell *Estu!*, and I do not mean *Let it be so!*, I really mean *Be!*.

So is it always context?  Or should I say *Vi estu!* if I mean *Be!*.  And if I want to say *Let it rain!* in the presence of a rain god and I don't want it to be interpreted as a command, should I say *Ĝi pluvu!*?  Or is *Vi estu!* a weaker statement such as *Let you be*?

Or is it correct to still think of both *Pluvu!* and *Estu!* both as commands, although normally directed towards some metaphorical entity, unless directed specifically towards the rain god and/or Hamlet?  In English when I yell *Rain!* I am saying *Let it rain!* but more forecfully, so it is a command towards some metaphorical entity.  On the other hand, if I, in English, say *Be!* I do not mean *Let it be so!*

Comment: Do people really say in English "Be!"?

Answer (score 2):

Unless a subject is specified, the implied subject of a u-verb is usually *vi*, as you had thought. When a verb can be used impersonally, however, such as *pluvi* or *esti* then it's possible that there is no implied subject.

The trouble, it seems to be, is with *esti* which can be used both personally and impersonally. This is not just a problem with *estu* but also comes into play with other forms.

- Estas bone havi amikojn. It is good to have friends.
- Estas problemo en mia respondo. There's a problem in my answer.

One might be tempted to ask whether *estas* like this means "it is" or "there is." The answer is -- read the whole sentence and try to understand it. The same thing applies if the verb ends in -u.